# Iterating through a concurrentHashMap of queues to see if all queues are empty, while other threads might add to queues

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, thread-sleep, concurrenthashmap

this is quite a specific question but we've been stuck for a while, and I searched the site for an answer and couldn't find it (first time ever!). So here we go:

My data structure is a concurrentHashMap. Each value in the map is a ConcurrentLinkedDeque of Actions (which is an abstract class I wrote extended by several actions - irrelevant to the question really). Queues are nicknamed 'actors'.

The basic program flow is:

There's an array of threads. Each thread iterates through the hash map, looking for actions to execute. If an actions queue is empty, the thread will move to the next queue. If it finds an action, the thread will pop it from the queue and execute the action. New actions are being submitted to the queues during the program's runtime in batches, only if all the previous actions are finished.

What happens if all queues are empty?
We want to avoid 'busy wait', so if all queues are empty, the thread will go to sleep. When will it wake up? we keep a 'Version Monitor', which basically counts how many actions were added to the program. The threads are sleeping on this counter.

New action submitted to program --> Version counter increments by one --> Threads wake up.

How do we know if all queues are empty? Well, the good old way - we iterate through them and check 'isEmpty' each time, while keeping an 'isAllEmpty' boolean.

So this is our problematic scenarios:

-All queues are empty.
-A thread iterates through all queues to see if they're empty.
-After the thread already checked a certain queue, a new action is submitted to this queue.

So here's what happened: the thread thinks all queues are empty, so he goes to sleep. He missed the 'wake up call' (Version number increased by one), because at that time he wasn't sleeping (but iterating through queues). No further actions will be submitted to the program, because the old batch of actions isn't finished yet. Threads waits for new actions, actions wait for thread. Deadlock.

How do we avoid this? We thought that using ConcurrentHashMap should fix this, but apparently it isn't safe to iterate through them. We're not allowed to use synchronized at all. We just don't know how to fix it.

I'm aware that this problem becomes less likely as the number of threads increases, but we needs to be able to run with a small amount of threads too - even one. And with one thread, this happens very often. What would you recommend?

Here's some relevant code:

```
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                if(actors.isEmpty())
                //if there's no actors, we need to wait until new actor will added to the hash map
                {
                    try {
                        vm.await(vm.getVersion());//waits until the version monitor will be changed
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
                //check if all queues are empty
                boolean isAllEmpty = true;
                Iterator <ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String, QueuePair>> it2 = actors.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it2.hasNext() && isAllEmpty){
                    if (!it2.next().getValue().queue.isEmpty())
                        isAllEmpty=false;
                }
                if(isAllEmpty)//all actors are empty
                {
                    try {
                        vm.await(vm.getVersion());//waits until the version monitor will be changed
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
                Iterator <ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String, QueuePair>>it = actors.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext())//if there is an available actors queue, execute one of it actions 
                {
                    //irrelevant code that executes the action
                }
            }
        }

        });
```

Thanks for answering :)

Comment: If all consumer threads are iterating through the `Map` (in arbitrary order, no less) to look for something to consume, then what is the point of multiple queues? Just have one queue and be done with it. The scanning for something to do is not very efficient either.

Comment: @Andreas - this isn't my design, it's a given assignment, and there's a lot more to it. There's some logic in the backstory - each queue is supposed to represent a different entity, and they're all supposed to work simultaneously. Each of those queues is also connected to more fields (notice it's actually an object called 'QueuePair') which sets them apart. It would be clearer if I described the whole assignment, but that's 18 pages and quite irrelevant to the question...

Comment: Make your version monitor a `Semaphore`. That way any thread that obtains a permit is guaranteed to find an action.